# In java implementation of Singly Linked List, Why is the last element of the linked list not being printed?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
public class Linked_List <E>{
    public static class Node<E>{
        private E element;
        private Node<E> next;
        public Node(E e,Node<E> n) {
        element=e;
        next=n;
    }
    public E getElement() {
        return element;
    }
    public Node<E> getNext() {
        return next;
    }
    public void setNext(Node<E> n) {
        next=n;
    }
}

public Node<E> head=null;
public Node<E> tail=null;
public int size=0;

public Linked_List() {}

public int size() {
    return size;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size==0;
}
public void addFirst(E e) {
    head=new Node<>(e,head);
    if(size==0)
        head=tail;
    size++;
}

public void addLast(E e) {
    Node<E> newest =new Node<>(e,null);
    if(isEmpty())
        head=newest;
    else
        tail.setNext(newest);
    tail=newest;
    size++;
}
public void show() {

    Node<E> n=head;
    if(size==0) {
        System.out.println("No elements to print");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    while(n.next!=null) {
        System.out.println(n.element);
        n=n.next;
    }
    System.out.println(n.element);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Linked_List<Integer> list = new Linked_List<Integer>();

    list.addFirst(10);
    list.addFirst(11);
    list.addFirst(12);

    list.show();

}
}
```

In show() method when the while reaches the last element of the list, it exits so the element doesn't get printed. Hence the last print statement in the show method.
I have added three elements into the list but when I execute the show() method only the first two elements that is 12 and 11 get printed. What is it that i am missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about here. This should say `tail = head`;

```
    public void addFirst(E e) {
        head = new Node<>(e, head);
        if (size == 0) {
            head = tail;
        }
        size++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

addFisrt() change to:

```
public void addFirst(E e) {
    head = new Node<>(e, head);
    size++;
}
```

you can debug addFirst(), the first element never add to LinkedList.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in the while loop condition:

```
while(n.next!=null) {
        System.out.println(n.element);
        n=n.next;
    }
```

When the list reaches element `n-1` it will print the element and then n will become `n=n.next` which is the last element. But now n being the last element his `n.next` will be null therefore while will break since the condition is not met anymore.

Comment: If you look closely, I have added a print statement outside of the while to print the last statement.

Answer (score -2):

You answered your own question:

> In show() method when the while reaches the last element of the list,
>   it exits so the element doesn't get printed.

This code:

```
while(n.next!=null) {
    System.out.println(n.element);
    n=n.next;
}
```

says  "while it's not the last element, print it".  i.e., the code explicitly does not want to print the last element.

I am here assuming that you're not including the final print statement in your problem description - that you added the final print to work around the while-loop problem.

You need:

```
while (n != null) {
    System.out.println(n.element);
    n = n.next;
}
```

which says 'while it is an actual element, print it'.

Comment: That is why i have added another print statement. I've checked that's not the problem

Comment: Then I misunderstood - I thought you'd added the extra print to solve the problem but wasn't sure why.  Still, there's no point in making your loop loop one less time than it needs to, and then fixing it by adding an extra print outside the loop.  I note I'm not the only person who misunderstood what you were asking